# What stats can be determined prior to trapping a ghost?

Tags: ghostbusters-world

Ghosts have several stats, like letter grade, star count, and various others that get wrapped up into a general CP rank.  Since I tend to burn through traps fairly quickly (and making more takes a while), tt would be nice if I could focus my catching efforts on better ghosts.

Is there a way to determine the stats of a ghost prior to throwing down a trap?